# Couldn't understand the assignment of Ruby instance variables in splatted way

Tags: ruby

I tried the below code to see if I can directly assign the instance variables or not outside the class without any explicit instance method call. Yes,the below code says I can.

```
  @ubuntu:~$ irb --simple-prompt
  class Foo
  def initialize(x,y,z)
  @x, @y, @z= x, y,z
  end
  def to_ary
  [@x, @y, @z]
  end
  def to_hash
  [@x => @y]
  end
  end
  #=> nil
  foo = Foo.new(10,11,12)
  #=> #<Foo:0x00000001191738 @x=10, @y=11, @z=12>
```

My Question is with the below :

```
 a,*b = foo
 #=> #<Foo:0x00000001191738 @x=10, @y=11, @z=12>
 a
 #=> 10
 b
 #=> [11, 12]
```

How or which internal method has been called to make such assignment to `a,*b` from instance variables without object creation?

Thanks

Comment: From the posts I read here: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/179710 this seems to be handled inside the Ruby parser.

Comment: if you format the bulk of the code without the irb prompts it's easier for readers - it enables them to copy and paste the code and reproduce the situation themselves.

Comment: @FrederickCheung thanks for the suggestion, will definitely keep in my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ruby interpreter needs the right side of a multiple assignment to be an array, so it goes through the normal procedure to get an array. Part of that procedure is to call `to_ary` on the target object. Your `to_ary` returns `[@x,@y, @z]`, and because of the behavior of splat, that results in `a = @x` and `b = [@y, @z]`.

Comment: But I didn't use `foo.to_ary` then how? Is it the automatic invocation of `to_ary` when with `=` operator?

Comment: @user2060534: Yes. When Ruby needs something to be something else, ti always tries methods like `to_ary`, `to_a`, etc. This is called duck typing.

Comment: Very good technical word - `duck typing` I never heard. I started it just 1.5 months back. So lot's to learn. I will definitely look into the concept.

Comment: Really... Could you give me some resources that you cam crosses at your beginning time, so that I can dipped into Ruby more. Any good online resources,blogs, or any of your personal codes that you tested when you were learning? This is really asking as personally. Please don't feel bad. Just asking to give me a Road map, as a help. If you want I can share my personal email ID too. But really teach me whenever I would stuck. Please..

Comment: @user2060534: Sure! Happy to help you. I think we should drop by the Ruby [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24194/ruby) for me to explain. Happy to help.

Comment: @user2060534: Just say something in chat when you get there.

Comment: Okay, I will- right now I don't have the access to chat tool as for firewall. But I will definitely do that, if you agree to help. Thanks for your warm help :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24772/discussion-between-linuxios-and-user2060534)

Comment: @user2060534: Try that link

Comment: not working I will be having access on that, when I reached home. After 3 hours I will be at home.

Comment: leaving only that chat link, all such personal talk please delete - I have no idea if anyone felt it bad or it is allowed here.

Comment: @user2060534: You're fine. Don't worry.